# read RS-232 and write data to CSV; Python in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, csv

I am having two problems...

1) **I cannot get my code to create a CSV file on the desktop**

2) **I cannot get my code to write data from serial cable every 5 seconds to the CSV file...**

Any assistance in my work would be great!

EDIT #2

```
import csv
import time
import threading
import serial
import os


time = time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H%M%S")
location = r'%s.csv' % time
outputfile = open(location, mode='x', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputfile)
outputWriter.writerow(['start'])
outputfile.close()

port = "COM4"

def SerialRead():
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)   
    out = ser.read(167)
    reading = str(out)
    plaintext = reading.replace(' ', ', ')
    plaintext = reading.replace('=', ', ')
    print(plaintext)
    ser.close()
    threading.Timer(4, SerialRead).start()

SerialRead()
```

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: All of it, do you really have a function nested inside a function and the threading.Timer inside each function? Also how does `SerialRead.plaintext.isblank()` work?

Comment: @NicholasRavanelli : Use spaces and not tabs. Check the PEP8 style, it will really help.

Comment: I would be ok with only making it 1 thread. however, I would want my serial connection to refresh every second and data to be written every 5 seconds to a csv. I still have the issue of not being able to make a csv file. It says directory invalid (which it is not).

Comment: @NicholasRavanelli, I cannot see how almost any of your code runs at all, there are numerous errors.

Comment: @roymustang86 I just copied my code from Spyder... indents might be off

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have updated the original thread with a working code. I am trying to get it to no copy the new line of code to a csv file... can you help integrate?

Comment: @roymustang86 I have updated the original thread with a working code. I am trying to get it to no copy the new line of code to a csv file... can you help integrate?

Comment: @NicholasRavanelli, the code should definitely create the file, are you saying `outputfile = open(location, mode='x', newline='')` does not create anything? What does `print os.getcwd()` output putting it at the start of your script?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want it to create the file to desktop... I cannot seem to get any python code to do this. I am on Windows 7.

Comment: Then your cwd is not your desktop directory, pass the full path to your desktop, `os.path.join("path_to_desktop",location)`

Comment: Your files are getting created where the python code is. Do as @PadraicCunningham says

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 'print os.getcwd()' gives me syntax error

Comment: add parens for python3  `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok found the directory, I want to change the working directory to my C:\User\SpO2\Desktop\Data\ .... how do I do this?

Comment: You can `os.chdir("C:\User\SpO2\Desktop\Data\ ....")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I also figured out that I had accidenttly forgot to place an 's' in Users... frig. LAST THING, my serial connection prints a line, and I want to replace ' ' and '=' with ', '. I can get it to replace my spaces, but not equals signs... why?

Comment: `plaintext = plaintext.replace('=', ', ')`, you never used the first plaintext, strings are immutable so you need to re-assign names to the result of any operations on a string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham feel like an absolute idiot... now my csv file wont make a new line every 5 seconds. i am using 'open(location, mode=w, newline='')'

Comment: You are opening with `w` so you overwrite each time, open the file with `a` or open once and pass the file object